# Google Calendar layout

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have been working with this php code, which should modify Google Calendars layout. But when I put the code to page, it makes everything below it disappear. What's wrong with it?

```
<?php
$your_google_calendar=" PAGE ";
$url= parse_url($your_google_calendar);
$google_domain = $url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].dirname($url['path']).'/';

// Load and parse Google's raw calendar
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLfile($your_google_calendar);

// Change Google's CSS file to use absolute URLs (assumes there's only one element)
$css = $dom->getElementByTagName('link')->item(0);
$css_href = $css->getAttributes('href');
$css->setAttributes('href', $google_domain . $css_href);

// Change Google's JS file to use absolute URLs
$scripts = $dom->getElementByTagName('script')->item(0);
foreach ($scripts as $script) {
$js_src = $script->getAttributes('src');
if ($js_src) { $script->setAttributes('src', $google_domain . $js_src); }
}

// Create a link to a new CSS file called custom_calendar.css
$element = $dom->createElement('link');
$element->setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
$element->setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
$element->setAttribute('href', 'custom_calendar.css');

// Append this link at the end of the element
$head = $dom->getElementByTagName('head')->item(0);
$head->appendChild($element);

// Export the HTML
echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm testing your code, I'm getting some errors because of wrong method call:

`->getElementByTagName` should be `->getElementsByTagName` with s on Element

and

`->setAttributes` and `->getAttributes` should be `->setAttribute` and `->getAttribute` without s at end.

I'm guessing that you don't have any error_reporting on, and because of that don't know anything went wrong?